# Printer canon MG5350 Grayscale and higher resolution

Tags: printing, resolution, canon

I installed the driver from canon for the MG5350 but I have the following problem:
By default there is only one resolution: 600dpi
You can only print in color

also I edit the .ppd file to add those parts

```
*OpenUI *Resolution/Output Resolution: PickOne
*DefaultResolution: 600dpi
*Resolution 300dpi/300 dpi: "<</HWResolution[300 300]>>setpagedevice"
*Resolution 600dpi/600 dpi: "<</HWResolution[600 600]>>setpagedevice"
*Resolution 1200dpi/1200 dpi: "<</HWResolution[1200 1200]>>setpagedevice"
*Resolution 2400dpi/2400 dpi: "<</HWResolution[2400 2400]>>setpagedevice"
*Resolution 2400x4800dpi/4800 dpi: "<</HWResolution[2400 4800]>>setpagedevice"
*Resolution 2400x9600dpi/9600 dpi: "<</HWResolution[2400 9600]>>setpagedevice"
*CloseUI: *Resolution

*OpenUI *CNGrayscale/Grayscale: PickOne
*DefaultCNGrayscale: false
*CNGrayscale false/Off: "false"
*CNGrayscale true/On: "true"
*CloseUI: *CNGrayscale
```

However: 
If I select the grayscale, it does print black and white, but the black is apparently made by mixing all the colors together instead of using the black cartridge.

Any idea

And by the way thumbs done to those bast... of Canon who after selling millions of printers still don't have what it takes to correctly support linux...

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody answered yet, I might as well do it (for future reference).
Go to your package-manager and install:
printer-driver-gutenprint

See here all the supported printers:
http://gimp-print.sourceforge.net/p_Supported_Printers.php

I hope this will work,
Jurgen